# Django Admin Complains About A Missing Field Even When It's Not Missing

Tags: django, django-admin

- Python 2.7
- Django 1.3

When I include `'user_id','user'` in the admin.py, then...

- no user field shows up in the form when I click to add a Timeslip.
- If I submit it anyway, then it shows the user field with a "**This field is required.**" error message.
- If I pick a user & submit again, then I get "**'TimeslipAdmin.fields' refers to field 'user_id' that is missing from the form.**" even though 'user_id' is *clearly listed in my admin.py* (see below)

The Traceback says --

- Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/timeslip/timeslip/add/
- Exception Value: 'TimeslipAdmin.fields' refers to field 'user_id' that is missing from the form.

But...if I leave `'user_id','user'` out of the admin.py then....

- no user field shows up when I click to add a Timeslip.
- Submit it anyway, and it shows the user field & a "**Timeslip with this User already exists.**" error message. (*which shouldn't be an error either 'cause I want users to have multiple Timeslip's which means another error I'll have to figure out once I can just get this form working*)

**admin.py**

```
from timeslip.models import Timeslip
from django.contrib import admin

class TimeslipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['user_id','user','day','hours_as_sec','part_of_day','drove','gas_money','notes']

admin.site.register(Timeslip, TimeslipAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Timeslip(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(User)
   day = models.DateField()
   hours_as_sec = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   part_of_day = models.CharField(max_length=16,choices=PART_O_DAY)
   drove = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   gas_money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
   notes = models.TextField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   url = models.URLField("Website", blank=True)
   position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I'm very clueless how to overcome this. I'm coming from a PHP background, a newbie to Python & Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_id` and `user` are redundant. Django automatically names your `user` field `user_id` in the database (since it holds the id for the User instance it points to.)

Change your admin.py to the following and it should work:

```
class TimeslipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['user','day','hours_as_sec','part_of_day','drove','gas_money','notes']
```

Also you're including all of the fields in the admin, so you really don't need to specify the fields. This would work just as well:

```
class TimeslipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: OOoohhh that seems to work! They should really reword that error mesaage 'cause I never would've guessed this from that message. Thanks! I didn't realize Django would know I'd want all the fields so I thought I should specify them all. Now I just got to figure out why it's limiting a timeslip per user. Hmmm. Maybe that's simpler than I'm expecting too.

Answer (score 0):

> But...if I leave 'user_id','user' out of the admin.py then...

You haven't got 'user_id' field. So delete only this field and I think everything will work fine.

Comment: The model specified it, and Django added a user_id field in the database table, so I figured I needed it so Django associated the form with the right user. Thanks.