# Django. user_id null & duplicate error

Tags: django

- Django 1.3
- Python 2.7

In [fixing one error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934158/django-admin-complains-about-a-missing-field-even-when-its-not-missing), I've developed another. I'm not even sure where to begin, I'm so frustrated.

I got my app to show up in the Django admin section, and when I click on "add", it brings up the form. When I fill it out & submit it, it results in this error:

Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Seems simple & clear, but if I add user_id to my admin.py, then it results in the error I just fixed. If I leave it out and use the code that fixes the old error, then I get this error. Here's the relevant code:

**admin.py** (I commented out the code I was using, as that caused the earlier error)

```
from timeslip.models import Timeslip
from django.contrib import admin

class TimeslipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
    #fields = ['user_id','day','hours_as_sec','part_of_day','drove','gas_money','notes']

admin.site.register(Timeslip, TimeslipAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Timeslip(models.Model):
   user=models.ManyToManyField(User)
   day = models.DateField()
   hours_as_sec = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   part_of_day = models.CharField(max_length=16,choices=PART_O_DAY)
   drove = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   gas_money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
   notes = models.TextField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   url = models.URLField("Website", blank=True)
   position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

If I make Timeslip's user=, into a `ForeignKey(User)` instead of a `ManyToManyField(User)`, the error becomes:

```
Exception Value: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'user_id'")
```

...which I understand, but that's exactly what I'm trying to do here now -- make multiple timeslips for each user.

How do I do that? I keep getting ridiculous errors no matter what I try, and it's hard finding documentation on this even though it seems like it would be a common & basic thing.

**Update:**

New question. Is Django caching stuff? I removed something from the model and reset everything but it still shows the old form. If it's showing me something it cached - *How do I flush that cache?*

Anyway, here's the output when I run `manage.py sqlall timeslip`

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `timeslip_timeslip` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `day` date NOT NULL,
    `hours_as_sec` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `part_of_day` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `drove` bool NOT NULL,
    `gas_money` numeric(5, 2) NOT NULL,
    `notes` longtext NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE `timeslip_timeslip` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_bb29929c` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);
CREATE TABLE `timeslip_userprofile_user` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `userprofile_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `user_id` integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`userprofile_id`, `user_id`)
)
;
ALTER TABLE `timeslip_userprofile_user` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_c73880a3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);
CREATE TABLE `timeslip_userprofile` (
     `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     `company` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE `timeslip_userprofile_user` ADD CONSTRAINT `userprofile_id_refs_id_d05b8c80` FOREIGN KEY (`userprofile_id`) REFERENCES `timeslip_userprofile` (`id`);
CREATE INDEX `timeslip_timeslip_fbfc09f1` ON `timeslip_timeslip` (`user_id`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hey @Forrest, when you add the Timeslip through your admin, are you selecting a user to add? How many users do you have in your db and which are you adding to Timeslip?

Comment: Yes, the form gives me a dropdown to select a user. Right now I only have 2 users, for testing purposes. I've used the form to create a timeslip entry for each user... after that, it won't let me add more for either user. I want to be able to create multiple timeslip entries for each user though.

Comment: i'm guessing your `user_id` field in the database (represented by the `user` field in your Django model) has a `unique=true` setting, which is causing the error. Can you run `manage.py sqlall [appname]` and post the results for the tables in question? Also can you launch your interactive database shell (usually just `manage.py dbshell` and view the `appname_timeslip` table? If you don't mind losing the data in your database you might want to try `manage.py reset [appname]` to clear your database and re-create everything based on your current models.

Comment: @rolling stone ...I added the output of `manage.py sqlall` above, and I see a unique in there. Is that my problem? How do I set it false? Also, I think I may be having a caching issue? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: you're right, here's the line that's causing you the problem: `CREATE INDEX 'timeslip_timeslip_fbfc09f1' ON 'timeslip_timeslip' ('user_id');` It's adding an index on `user_id`. Try running the following command in your dbshell and let me know if that worked: `DROP INDEX 'timeslip_timeslip_fbfc09f1' ON 'timeslip_timeslip';`