# user_id may not be NULL

Tags: django, post, django-models, curl

I'm serving my Django models via TastyPie and when attempting to POST a new Booking model, I keep getting this error:

```
error_message: "bookings_booking.user_id may not be NULL"
```

Even using curl produces it:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"date": "2011-08-17", "time": "17:30", "duration": 30, "description": "meh", "user": "/api/v1/user/1/", "room": "/api/room/1/"}' http://localhost:8000/api/booking/
```

I have tried deleting my database and run syncdb multiple times already but the problem persists.

Here are my Django models:

```
class User(models.Model):
login       = models.CharField('login', max_length=12)
password    = models.CharField('password', max_length=12)
fullname    = models.CharField('fullname', max_length=30)

class Room(models.Model):
name        = models.CharField('room name', max_length=30)
code        = models.CharField('room code', max_length=4)

class Booking(models.Model):
date        = models.DateField('date booked')
time        = models.TimeField('time booked')
duration    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('duration booked') #x * 15
user        = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bookings')
room        = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='bookings')
description = models.TextField()
```

And here's my Tastypie resources:

```
class RoomResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'room'

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

class BookingResource(ModelResource):
    room = fields.ForeignKey(RoomResource, 'room')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Booking.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'booking'
        filtering = {
            "room"  :   ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            "date"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
            "time"  :   ['gte', 'lte']
        }
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Comment: trying the solution at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949345/django-user-id-null-duplicate-error) but I get a syntax error on the SQL statement: `sqlite> DROP INDEX "bookings_booking_fbfc09f1" ON "bookings_booking" ("user_id");
Error: near "ON": syntax error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add a user FK to your `BookingResource`. Like So::

```
class BookingResource(ModelResource):
    room = fields.ForeignKey(RoomResource, 'room')
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserREsource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Booking.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'booking'
        filtering = {
            "room"  :   ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            "date"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
            "time"  :   ['gte', 'lte']
        }
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that. Had so much code coming out my ears lately.